# Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (View:

Tags: laravel

I run the following code to display my one to many relationship, however i receive the error: Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (View:

This is my code: PostsController.php

```
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $review = Post::find(1)->reviews()->where('title', 'posts_title')->first();
    //$review = Review::all();

    return view('posts.show', compact('post', 'review'));
}
```

Post.php

```
   protected $tables='reviews';

  function reviews(){

      return $this->hasMany('App\Review', 'title', 'post_title');

    }
```

From the stack trace the error is around here:

```
    @if(count($review) > 1)

    @foreach($review as $reviews)
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: You're tryring to iterate through`$review` but it's an object since you're getting it with `->first();`

Comment: Do you know different between `first()`, `get()`, and `all()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using ->first() you receive one object and then you can neither use count nor iterate with @foreach

So here is your mistake:

```
// object
$review = Post::find(1)->reviews()->where('title', 'posts_title')->first();

// collection
$reviews = Post::find(1)->reviews()->where('title', 'posts_title')->get();
```

on $reviews you can then use

```
@if($reviews->count() > 1)

@foreach($reviews as $review)
```

Comment: I now get this error: ErrorException compact(): Undefined variable: review on line: -> return view('posts.show', compact('post', 'review')). Even though 'review' was working before ?

Comment: `return view('posts.show', compact('post', 'reviews'));` if you renamed your variable to $reviews the compact method needs 'reviews' as parameter

Comment: awesome that kinda worked however it doesnt display my data. I have data present in my SQL tables but it is not outputing anything (i am kinda new to laravel) so please excuse my mistakes

Answer (score 0):

The count() method in PHP expects countable object or array or collection. If any other data type like string, null or empty values passed, It strictly throws fatal error in PHP version 7.X but PHP 5.x just says warning and continue to execute.

You can avoid this by using empty function

```
@if(!empty($review))

    @foreach($review as $reviews)
```

Comment: this kinda worked however none of my posts are now appearing